# CORS error in Keycloak custom REST endpoint

Tags: cors, keycloak

So I've read the documentation on how to extend the server here:

> https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_development/topics/extensions.html

and followed this tutorial:

> https://dev.to/silentrobi/keycloak-custom-rest-api-search-by-user-attribute-keycloak-3a8c

I'm trying to get users by a custom attribute and so far it is working when I try it with Postman. However, when I tried to send the get request from my angular app it returned the CORS error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. I've tried adding the @CrossOrigin annotation with localhost as the origin but it didn't work. I also tried setting the headers manually on the response with * or localhost as the origin like this:

---

```
    @GET
    @Path("users/search_by_attribute")
    @NoCache
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Encoded
    public Response searchUsersByAttribute(@DefaultValue(searchBy) @QueryParam("attribute") String attribute, @QueryParam("value") String value) {
                List<UserDto> list = session.users().searchForUserByUserAttribute(attribute, value, session.getContext().getRealm()).stream().map(e -> userMapper.mapToUserDto(e)).collect(Collectors.toList());
                return Response.status(200)
                .header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
                .entity(list)
                .build();
    }
```

---

But it also didn't work. Is there a way to configure CORS on the endpoint or the server?

Comment: I guess that browser firstly tries to perform CORS preflight request that is not handled by your endpoint. See JAX-RS preflight CORS handling examples in internet. Afaik in keycloak sources you can find one. Try to search by classname with "Cors" token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to respond to preflight OPTIONS request as mentioned by @solveMe.

```
@OPTIONS
@Path("{any:.*}")
public Response preflight() {
    HttpRequest request = session.getContext().getContextObject(HttpRequest.class);
    return Cors.add(request, Response.ok()).auth().preflight().build();
}
```

session is KeycloakSession. Cors class is in org.keycloak.services.resources

Comment: I had to make a small modification ti the example:

        HttpRequest request = session.getContext().getHttpRequest();

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [Repo](https://github.com/el-abdel/keycloak-custom-rest-endpoint) that may help you, it's a Keycloak Custom endpoint to get users by custom attribute, that i used with my Angular Application, Cors Errors are handled and Authentication is implemented.